# How does my JavaScript power function work?

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, return

```
var power = function (base, exponent) {
  var result = 1;
  for ( i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
    result = result * base;
  }
  return result;
};

power(2, 2);
```

I actually I get some of it, what I don't get is --
What does the for loop do in there and the lines after?(of the function power)

Answer (score 4):

The loop loops from `0` (inclusive) to `exponent` (exclusive) multiplying `result` by `base` and storing the result in `result`. Once it's looped that many times, it returns the result. So it's raising the number to a given power (see [*exponentiation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation)).

---

Side note: This code falls prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because it fails to declare the `i` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Raising a number to a certain power is the same as multiplying that number by itself that many times; so 2 raised to the power of 2 is the same as 2 * 2, 2 raised to the power of 3 is the same as 2 * 2 * 2, etc. The `for` loop simply implements that.

Answer (score 2):

The function actually calculates the power function in the straight forward way by multiplying the base multiple times with itself.

The loop actually multiplies the intermediate result with the base in reach run. Thereby calculating `result = (((1 * base) * base) * base) * ...` to get the final result.

Btw there is a built in function for this: `Math.pow` ([see MDN for details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow))